# Putting x-axis labels directly under tick marks in barplots in R

Tags: r, graphics, format, bar-chart

I have a table (below) showing the percentage of tree species (categorical variable) present in a group experiment. My objective is to plot the percentage of tree species on the y-axis and 'Species' on the x-axis within a barplot.

[image]

**Issue**

My problem is that I am experiencing problems with formatting the x-axis correctly. My objective is to ensure that the x-axis labels for**'Species'** are:-

1. Positioned directly underneath their bar at the tick mark
2. Do not overlap onto the plotting area

If anyone can help solve this issue, I would be incredibly grateful.

[image]

**R code**

```
  df <- leaf.percent[order(leaf.percent$Leaf.Percentge, decreasing = TRUE),]

  Tree.labels<-c("Quercus robar", "Quercus Patraea",
                 "Deciduous", "Oak",
                 "Plant", "Shrub")

  par(mar=c(6, 6, 3, 3))

  Tree<-barplot(df$Leaf.Percentge, names.arg = df$Species,
                xaxt = "n",
                ylab="Percentage %", 
                xlab="Tree Species",
                col="lightblue",
                ylim = c(0, 60))

    axis(1, at=Tree, labels=FALSE)

    text(seq(1, 6, by=1), par("usr")[3] - 0.2, 
         labels=unique(Tree.labels), 
         srt = 25, pos = 1, 
         xpd = TRUE, cex=0.7)
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Species = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Deciduous", 
"Oak", "Plant", "Quercus_petraea", "Quercus_robur", "Shrub"), class =     "factor"), 
Frequency = c(48L, 29L, 6L, 70L, 206L, 4L), Leaf.Percentge =     c(13.2231404958678, 
7.98898071625344, 1.65289256198347, 19.2837465564738, 56.7493112947658, 
1.10192837465565)), .Names = c("Species", "Frequency", "Leaf.Percentge"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```